# inner holes in segmentation polygons -coco dataset

Tags: image-processing, object-detection, mask, pycocotools

So to explain the problem
I have a dataset with the coco format
I want to reconstruct the binary mask from the segmentation information stored in the annotation json file

here is the
[target mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPSPw.png)

in here it is [the reconstructed mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvicX.png)

As you can see the inside hole is messing in the reconstructed mask

the mask was reconstructed using the following code

```
from pycocotools import mask as maskUtils
def annToRLE( ann, height, width):
        """
        Convert annotation which can be polygons, uncompressed RLE to RLE.
        :return: binary mask (numpy 2D array)
        """
        segm = ann['segmentation']
        if isinstance(segm, list):
            # polygon -- a single object might consist of multiple parts
            # we merge all parts into one mask rle code
            rles = maskUtils.frPyObjects(segm, height, width)
            rle = maskUtils.merge(rles)
        elif isinstance(segm['counts'], list):
            # uncompressed RLE
            rle = maskUtils.frPyObjects(segm, height, width)
        else:
            # rle
            rle = ann['segmentation']
        return rle

def annToMask( ann, height, width):
    """
    Convert annotation which can be polygons, uncompressed RLE, or RLE to binary mask.
    :return: binary mask (numpy 2D array)
    """
    rle = annToRLE(ann, height, width)
    m = maskUtils.decode(rle)
    return m
```

is there a way to keep the inside hole?

Comment: Using OpenCV or PIL library these can be filled. First find the contour in the image and fill the inner pixels

Answer (score 0):

Well the solution I found is to delete the line

```
rle = maskUtils.merge(rles)
```

change variable name

```
rles = maskUtils.frPyObjects(segm, height, width)
```

to

```
rle = maskUtils.frPyObjects(segm, height, width)
```

this is inside the function annToRLE

and after you call annToMask

```
m = annToMask(sets,width,hight)
```

we check if there is multiple masks, add the masks into one mask, overlays between masks will be expressed as value greater than 2, so we set these values to zero

```
if m.ndim >= 2:
                  reduced=np.add.reduce(m,axis=2)
                  m = np.where(reduced>=2,0,reduced)
```